# Link Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My Android app runs well as release build.
However, debug build doesn't.

Android Studio, SDK, and more, each environment is newest version.

With debug build, emulators run with many warning, but a real device crashes as soon as launched with following logcat.

> W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$2;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1; (229) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link
>   of class 'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2; (229) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link
>   of class 'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1; (918)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1; (918)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompatIcs$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatICS$1; (11)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatICS$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1;
>   (948) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatKitKat$1;
>   (948) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatKitKat$1;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$2;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView; (1026)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics$b;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment; (25) W/dalvikvm﹕
>   Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment;'
>   failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager$e;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment; (26) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of
>   class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;' failed W/dalvikvm﹕
>   Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaFragment; (26)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaFragment;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/tagmanager/bb$1; (884) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of
>   class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/tagmanager/bb$1;' failed W/dalvikvm﹕
>   Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragment; (26)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragment;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
>   Lcom/google/tagmanager/LRUCache$1; (884) W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/tagmanager/LRUCache$1;' failed W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lfacebook4j/management/APIStatisticsOpenMBean;' failed W/dalvikvm﹕
>   Link of class 'Ltwitter4j/management/APIStatisticsOpenMBean;' failed
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
>   'Lcom/google/android/gms/games/internal/PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1;'
>   failed E/dalvikvm﹕ LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=2184
>   E/dalvikvm﹕ VM aborting

My build.gradle wrote

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
//          jni.srcDirs = ['jni']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('~~~~~.keystore')
            storePassword '********'
            keyAlias '~~~~~'
            keyPassword '********'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://twitter4j.org/maven2' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
//  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.facebook4j:facebook4j-core:1.1.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

I tried to clean gradle and this android project, remove cache (~/.gradle) and build directory.
However problem not cleared.

It seems that, libraries installed with gradle are not linked or include to the application.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=1092 Error while instaling on my Samsung Tablet Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413898/linearalloc-exceeded-capacity-5242880-last-1092-error-while-instaling-on-my-s)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are facing is your generic gradle home dir (~/.gradle) does not have (or load) the libraries required for your project. (There maybe more about it. But, that's all of my understanding)

It mostly happen if the project is downloaded from Github.

> There has to be a directory name "gradle" inside the download project.
>   What you can do is, go to Preferences of Android Studio -> Go to
>   "Gradle" -> and in update "Service directory path" with the path of
>   gradle folder inside the your downloaded project.

Android Studio will start fetching the libraries for the projects. It takes about 20 minutes. And when you Sync again, it should be ok.

PS: There might some logic related to gradle build for this problem. But, I haven't learn those yet. So, hope that might help you.