# Can't install apk via Android Studio or adb with the apk build by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I download an android project source code from github and open it with Android Studio, but when I click the "run app" button, after some while I got this error:

> Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error).
>   In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

And I got this error in the console

```
$ adb push D:\work\zuoyexitong\third-part-projects\AndroidAudioRecorder\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.example
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.example"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.example
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

But I'm sure I didn't install this apk before. And if I click "ok" to let Android Studio to uninstall the app, i got this error

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall cafe.adriel.androidaudiorecorder.example
Unknown failure (Failure)
Error while Installing APK
```

My Android Stuido Version is : 2.2.3 .

The project i use is [here](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioRecorder)

My device's android version is 4.1.1 .

My problem looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577329/installation-failed-since-the-device-possibly-has-stale-dexed-jars-that-dont-ma) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493310/cant-upload-android-app-to-device-stale-dexed-jars) , but they can't solve my problem.

So how to solve this problem?

Comment: After reset my device. The problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is because there is an old version of your app installed on the device that has a `dex` size different from the current one you are trying to install, so you should press `OK` and proceed!

> But I'm sure I didn't install this apk before.

Check if you are using the same package name of another app that is installed on your device [most probably by you]!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have add some info of my question, this maybe helpful to description my question. And I am really sure I didn't install this app before.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Instant Run in Android Studio:
File / Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Instant Run / uncheck the top box.

If this allows successful installs, then turn instant run back on, and see if the problem comes back.  It did for me - I just hit this issue on a small test program at AS2.4P7.   The instant run feature is a light switch -on gives this error (even after refactoring) - off and the app loads OK.   If it problem comes back when you turn on instant run again, then file a bug report - Help / Report Instant Run Issue...

Answer (score 0):

check you have space left for app install. Try uninstalling some apps and try this app install.

Comment: Thanks Deep, but the space of my device that I can use to install app is almost 3.5GB, I got this info from Settings app.