# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT + mismatched uid

Tags: android, installation, dex

My apk installs and runs fine on xPeria Active (Android 2.3.4). But on Samsung GT-S6102 (Android 2.3.6) I'm seeing this error when trying to install:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT 
Please check logcat output for more details. 
Launch canceled!
```

I tried restarting the phone and uninstalling all apps with my signature, but this didn't help.
The apk is just 3 MB in size and there is 100 MB free space available on the phone.

The logcat shows these errors:

```
E/PackageManager(1525): Package com.mopub.simpleadsdemo has mismatched uid: 10071 on disk, 10068 in settings
E/dalvikvm(2220): LinearAlloc exceeded capacity (5242880), last=1352
E/dalvikvm(2220): VM aborting
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-S6102/GT-S6102:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/XXMA3:user/release-keys'
pid: 2220, tid: 2220  >>> /system/bin/dexopt <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
[...stack, code around r...]
E/PowerManagerService(1525): CurLock p:3 mPS:1
E/liblog(1322): failed to call dumpstate
E/installd(1328): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.mopub.simpleadsdemo-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 11
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8413898/1233652? Also, see [this](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920).